# Age calculation - Fastest age calculation formula from timestamp field

Tags: mysql

I'm using this query to calc an user age:

```
SELECT 
((YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(um.date_birth)) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(um.date_birth,5))) 
FROM user_meta AS um
WHERE um.uid = 2
```

I wonder if there's a fastest / lighter way to do it. 
I'm using this nested in a bigger select, so I wouldn't mind to somehow enhance the overall performance. Thank you.

Comment: How long does one of these queries take?

Comment: what is the data type of date_birth field?

Comment: Is this query being run each time the page is loaded? Or is it being run on an as-needed basis?

Comment: Ozzy: It's fast and works. I'm just looking for a more intelligent approach on it.
Heximal: It's a timestamp field.
Maiorano84: It's a block from a search function so yes, each page load, limit to 15 records.

Comment: I think the reason why you want to change it is for readability, not for performance (which is reasonable). I benchmarked it on my system and it's pretty damn fast: 25 million executions in 600ms. Details: Windows 7 64 bit OS with a Core i3-2330M CPU and MySQL version 5.5.16. The `date_birth` column in my case was of type `DATE`.

Comment: @SoboLAN Readability for sure, but overall performance as well, as I'm using this code as a JOIN inside another search query. 
I'm trying to improve the search query performance by working on smaller blocks. Here is another [question I just asked minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324032/date-calculation-ranking-assign-a-value-for-event-age) about date calculations that is used on the same query (yeap, it's a big refined search query).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (CURDATE()-birth_dt)/365 from dual
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact it would be:
SELECT (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(um.date_birth)) FROM dual;

Much shorter, thanks!

Comment: This answer does not take into account leap years which have 366 days

Answer (score 1):

If you find that you need to calculate a field too often, I would suggest you ALTER your table to add new columns to facilite your calculations.

For example, rather than calculate the YEAR for each date of birth in each query, simple add a YEAR column, update the table ONCE with the year of birth, and store the year as an INT.

That way, every time you need to catch the year, just select the field.

Comment: Yeap, that would be clever. Thank you.