# Date calculation ranking - Assign a value for event age

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to assign a value for events based on it's age using this:

```
SELECT u.iduser, timeIsImportant
FROM user AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
SELECT action, user_id, action_time, 
    (IF(bb.action_time < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), 
      (CASE 
       WHEN bb.action_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND CURDATE() THEN 0.1 
       WHEN bb.action_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND CURDATE() THEN 0.2
       WHEN bb.action_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND CURDATE() THEN 0.4
       WHEN bb.action_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH) AND CURDATE() THEN 0.7
       WHEN bb.action_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 MONTH) AND CURDATE() THEN 1.0
       END), 0)) 
AS timeIsImportant
FROM bigbrother AS bb
ORDER BY bigbrother.uid DESC LIMIT 1) 
AS bbb 
ON
bbb.user_id = u.iduser AND bbb.action = "C"
WHERE u.iduser = 2;
```

The idea is that older 'events' on the bigbrother table need to subtract different values from a ranking query calculation. The timeIsImportant value from the query above, would be the agePoints on the following example.

sample data:

```
     row1                              row2
 -------------                    -------------
 rank: 4.7                         rank 4.9
 agePoints: 0.1                    agePoints 0.4
 timedRank: (rank-AgePoints)       timedRank: (rank-AgePoints)

 -------------------------------------------------------------

 SQL: ORDER BY timedRank DESC

 row1, row2

 SQL: ORDER BY timedRank ASC

 row2, row1
```

**I wonder if there's another way to assign the values based on events age**, since I'm doing this calculation on every page load in order to rank search results and found that this piece of code slows the overall performance when nested within the search query.

Comment: How large is the table? I would store AgePoints in the table. You can set up a cron script to run once a day and update the AgePoints, this way when you need to order search results you can just use direct queries without conditionals.

Comment: Big table is big. At this point a cron is not an option for me. Other than that, I wonder if there's a more intelligent approach on that query (as it's working anyway). Nevertheless, funny thing that everyone suggests the "create another column" thing. That's the easy route and I wanna rock this db :)